# Difference between 'through' and 'throughout'

Tags: differences, adverbs

I'm not sure which is correct:

> The bride's mother sniffed all the way through/throughout the wedding service.

According to the Cambridge dictionary, '***through***' means 'from the beginning to the end of a period of time. '***Throughout***' means 'in every part, or during the whole period of time'. Does that mean both are acceptable? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage would be

```
The bride's mother sniffed all through the wedding service.
```

AND

```
The bride's mother sniffed throughout the wedding service.
```

Check [this](http://pediaa.com/difference-between-through-and-throughout/) and [this](http://wikidiff.com/throughout/through) for more ideas.